# Parse csv string into columns in python

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I have a csv file containing two columns. The first one is a stringID whereas the second one is a list of stringIDs.

> Column1 | Column2
>
> aaa    | [u'xxx', u'yyy']

My question is how to create a new csv with the stringIDs in pairs (two columns with duplicates)? For example,

> Column1 | Column2
>
> aaa     | u'xxx'
>
> aaa     | u'yyy'

Thanks a lot for helping me! I know this problem should be simple but it has been bothering me for days...

Comment: If it's been bothering you for days you should have some code you've tried. Please share that with us.

Comment: Can you give us what you have in code so we can help you? We aren't here to do work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This code ignores the possibility that csv-style processing could be used, since I wasn't sure exactly how fields are delimited. I've assumed that they are separated by a '|' character and that it could be necessary to strip blanks. I have taken advantage of a comment in using `ast.literal_eval` for safe processing of the lists.

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import ast
>>> inputCSV = StringIO('''\
... Column1 | Column2
... aaa | [u'xxx', u'yyy']
... bbb | [u'sss', u'ttt']''')
>>> header = True
>>> with inputCSV as inCSV:
...     for line in inCSV.readlines():
...         
...         column1, column2 = [_.strip() for _ in line.split('|')]
...         
...         
...         if header:
...             print ('%s|%s' % (column1, column2))
...             header = False
...         else:
...             column2 = ast.literal_eval(column2)
...             
...             for item in column2:
...                 print ('%s|%s' % (column1, item))
... 
Column1|Column2
aaa|xxx
aaa|yyy
bbb|sss
bbb|ttt
```

Comment: It is almost always the wrong choice to use `eval()`. [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast.literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) would work just as well while being much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the constructive answer! Although it didn't quite work for me specifically, I was definitely inspired by it and came up with some functional code!

```
header = True

with open('2.csv') as inCSV:
writer = csv.writer(open('1.csv', 'wb'))
for line in inCSV.readlines():
    column1, column2 = [_.strip() for _ in line.split(',',1)]
    if header:
        writer.writerow(('source','target'))
        header = False
    else:
        temp=column2.replace("[","]").replace("]","").replace('"','').split(",")
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            data=(column1,temp[i])
            writer.writerow(data)
```